# Filter a C# List dictionary based on the another dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dictionary, data-filtering

Firstly, I have data stored in a Dictionary (this could be from a database or from an uploaded excel file)

```
var allData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
if (task.DataSourceId == (int)DataSource.CurrentSubscriber)
  {
    allData = DBTools.Tools().Helper.GetCurrentSubscribers(task.Parent.CustomerId, task.Parent.DatabaseGroupId, DateTime.Now, out mem);
  }
else
  {
    allData = task.Parent.InputFile ? GetCsvRows(task, false) : GetDbRowsMulti(task, true, false, out mem);
  }
```

Secondly, I want to have a filter like a price is greater than or smaller than, as seen in the image below. [image]

```
var filterConditions = DBTools.Tools().Helper.GetTaskDataFilterMapping(task.Parent.TaskId);
```

I have stored these filters in the database and this is how we could get it as a second dictionary.

Now, my question is how can I filter the first data based on these data filters?

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: Since Dictionary implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>, you can just use Where

Comment: Not sure how I would use Where for this

Comment: where !exists<id> etc - google `linq` & `exists`